# Python. После ввода переменных в программе в случае U, программа не выводит текст, а просто крашится

Tags: python

```
from stegano import lsb
import ctypes
import time
import os
import sys

CorrectFolder = "CoderDecoder"
FolderPath = "C:\\Program Files\\"
PinWay = "C:\\Program Files\\CoderDecoder\\Pincode.txt"

def run_as_admin():
    if not ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " 
".join(sys.argv), None, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_as_admin()

if not os.path.isfile(PinWay):
    print("Файл пинкода не существует или поврежден. Запустите установку через 'install' или выйдите из программы через 'exitberr'.")
    installChoice = input()
    if installChoice == "install":
        print("Придумайте Пин Код. Он необходим для доступа к основной функции приложения.")
        NewPin = input()
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(PinWay), exist_ok=True)
        with open(PinWay, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(NewPin)

    elif installChoice == "exitberr":
        print("Вы решили пропустить средство восстановления/остановки. Выход из программы через 5 секунд")
        time.sleep(5)
        quit()

with open(PinWay, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    TruePin = file.read()

print("Закодировать или раскодировать текст? C - закодировать / U - раскодировать")
choice = input()

if choice == "C":
    print("Напишите Пин код.")
    pincode = int(input())

    if pincode == int(TruePin):
        print("Напишите путь к фото-тексту")
        way = input()
        print("Напишите скрытый текст")
        text = input()
        image = lsb.hide(way, text)
        image.save(way)
        print("Для выхода напишите 'quitp'")
        a = input()
        if a == 'quitp':
            quit()
    else:
        print("Пин код неверный, доступ отклонен!")
        quit()

elif choice == "U":
    print("Напишите Пин код.")
    pincode = input()  # Read PIN code as a string
    if pincode == TruePin:
        print("Напишите путь к фото-тексту")
        way = input()
        hidden_text = lsb.reveal(way)
        print(hidden_text)
        print("Для выхода напишите 'quitp'")
        a = input()
        if a == 'quitp':
            quit()
    else:
        print("Пин код неверный, доступ отклонен!")
        time.sleep(3)
        quit()
else:
    print("Вы выбрали несуществующее действие. Закройте программу")
    quit()
```

## C:\Program Files\apple.jpg

Comment: Укажите, какая ошибка выводится при краше вашей программы. В теме письма не надо задавать вопрос, прочитайте правила.